# Prepared statement nested inside another prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to figure out how to run a second prepared statement within another prepared staments loop. Not optimal, but don't know how else I can solve this...

Here is what I am trying:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

### GET THE CURRENT USERS FRIENDS ###
$sql = "SELECT f.fk_user_id2
             , u.username
             , u.profileimg FROM ".$prefix."_friends f 
                INNER JOIN ".$prefix."_users u
                    ON f.fk_user_id2 = u.id     
            WHERE f.fk_user_id1 = ? ORDER BY u.username ASC";

if($stmt->prepare($sql)){

    $stmt->bind_param('i',$playerid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($userPoints);
    while ($stmt->fetch()){

        $friendid = $row1['fk_user_id2'];
        $friendname = $row1['username'];
        if(empty($row1['profileimg'])){
            $profileimg = 'http://duefmun.dk/profileimages/noimage.png';
        } else {
            $profileimg = 'http://duefmun.dk/profileimages/'.$row1['profileimg'];
        }

        ### GET THE HISTORY ###
        $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT wins, games FROM ".$prefix."_newversus WHERE fk_player=? AND fk_opponent=?");
        if($stmt->prepare($sql1)){
            $stmt->bind_param('ii',$playerid,$friendid);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($wins,$games);
            $stmt->fetch();

            if($games == 0){
                $history = $languagestring[165];
            } else {
                $history = $languagestring[168].' '.$wins.' '.$languagestring[169].' '.$games.' '.$languagestring[170];
            }
        }

        $string .= $friendname.','.$friendid.','.$history.','.$profileimg.'^';

    }
} 

$string = substr($string,0, (strlen($string)-1)); 
echo $string.'%';

$stmt->close();
```

Maybe it is possible to innerjoin the second statement, but don't know how. Please help and thanks in advance :-/

Comment: Why is the 'friends' and 'newversus' tied to the table name? That rather defeats the purpose of using a relational DB.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a prepared statement is your problem but just a *variable*
You are just rewriting your variable, $stmt in this case.
Give it another name  for the second loop (and check other variables invloved)

Comment: Ok, but what about this: $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init(); Should I start a new of these every time then?